# Stop automatic form submitting on Select attribute in HTML form in Angular js

Tags: html, angular

I am making a form where user can select their branch.

This is my form-

```
<form method="post" [formGroup]="formData" (click)="dataSubmit()" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="branch">Select Branch</label>
        <select [formControl]="branchControl" class="form-control" id="branch">
          <option value="cs">CS</option>
          <option value="it">IT</option>
          <option value="me">ME</option>
          <option value="ece">ECE</option>
          <option value="civil">CIVIL</option>
          <option value="ene">ENE</option>
          <option value="eie">EIE</option>
        </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I am selecting any branch, It automatically submit branch without clicking on submit button.

How to stop that. Please help

Comment: remove click event, and add onsubmit event

Comment: @Observer But it is not an angular event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Angular2+ not AngularJS, here is the [form tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). The reason your form is submitted when you select a branch is because of this code:

```
<form method="post" [formGroup]="formData" (click)="dataSubmit()" >
```

The `(click)="dataSubmit()"` tells angular to submit the form if anything in the form is clicked. Replace it with: `(ngSubmit)="dataSubmit()"`

You can now change your button to:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Now the form will only be submitted if you click your button.

Answer (score 0):

It works when apply click event on button

```
<button (click)="dataSubmit()" type="submit"></button>
```